# Eonasdan Bootstrap Datetimepicker - Can't set minDate to now with current time

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs, date-format, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I need to set the min date to the current with time. But it's only working when i set the date without time. I've tried several time formats and found no solution.

Here are my settings

Default:

```
settings: {
    locale: 'de',
    viewMode: 'days',
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY',
    useStrict: true,
    focusOnShow: false,
    showClose: true,
},
```

Datepicker Settings:

```
this.$time_from.datetimepicker($.extend(true, DefaultDatepicker.settings, {
    minDate: DefaultDatepicker.getDateRange(0),
    maxDate: DefaultDatepicker.getDateRange(365),
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm',
    viewMode: 'days'
}));
```

Output: *08. November 2016 - 00:00*

Function to calculate the date:

```
getDateRange: function (max) {
    var CurDate = new Date();
    CurDate.setDate(CurDate.getDate() + max);
    var mm = CurDate.getMinutes();
    var hh = CurDate.getHours();
    var dd = CurDate.getDate();
    var mm = CurDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = CurDate.getFullYear();

    //return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y + ' ' + hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss; //not working output: 2016-11-08T14:18:45+01:00 + error

    return mm + '/' + dd + '/' + y;
},
//Example getDateRange(0) = now, getDateRange(1) = tomorrow
```

TESTED:
Also not working

```
newgetDateRange: function (max) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + max);
    var ss = ( '0' + (date.getSeconds())).slice(-2);
    var mm = ( '0' + (date.getMinutes())).slice(-2);
    var hh = ( '0' + (date.getHours())).slice(-2);
    var d = ( '0' + (date.getDate())).slice(-2);
    var M = ( '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2);
    var Y = date.getFullYear();

    var $new = Y + '-' + M + '-' + d + 'T' + hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss + 'Z';
    return $new;
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is the format of the result of `getDateRange` function, probably it should return the date in the `DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm` format.

The docs [says (for the `date` function)](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#date):

> Parsing of the newDate parameter is made using moment library with the `options.format` and `options.useStrict` components configuration.

I think that it use the same logic for the [`minDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#mindate) and [`maxDate`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#maxdate) options.

Anyway `minDate` and `maxDate` both accepts moment object, so your `getDateRange` function can return a moment instead of a string and you can simply use [`add()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) to get your range.

Here a working example:

```js
var DefaultDatepicker = {
  settings: {
    locale: 'de',
    viewMode: 'days',
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY',
    useStrict: true,
    focusOnShow: false,
    showClose: true,
  },
  getDateRange: function(max){
    return moment().add(max, 'days');
  }
};

$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker($.extend(true, DefaultDatepicker.settings, {
    minDate: DefaultDatepicker.getDateRange(0),
    maxDate: DefaultDatepicker.getDateRange(365),
    format: 'DD. MMMM YYYY - HH:mm',
    viewMode: 'days'
}));
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/locale/de.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.42/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: you're welcome @jamie! Don't forget to upvote (if you think that the answer deserves it) when you'll have enough reputation :)